# How can I protect my GKE cluster against master node failure?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

In GKE every cluster has a single master endpoint, which is managed by Google Container Engine. Is this master node high available?

I deploy a beautiful cluster of redundant nodes with kubernetes but what happen if the master node goes down? How can i test this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to what Robert Bailey said about GKE keeping the master available for you, it's worth noting that Kubernetes / GKE clusters are designed (and tested) to continue operating properly in the presence of failures. If the master is unavailable, you temporarily lose the ability change what's running in the cluster (i.e. schedule new work or modify existing resources), but everything that's already running will continue working properly.

Comment: Thanks @AlexRobinson.

Answer (score 3):

In Google Container Engine the master is managed for you and kept running by Google. According to the [SLA for Google Container Engine](https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/sla) the master should be available at least 99.5% of the time.

Comment: Does it makes sense to create a separate master in another zone for high availability ?

Comment: You can create a regional GKE cluster to get a control plane that is resilient to single zone outages.